# Unable to find the react native variable "ConnectionStatus"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to implement a code that tests the internet connectivity using react native **NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo'**. It is giving me an error that says **"Can't find variable: connectionStatus"**. I tried my best declare properly but for some reason it is giving the error above.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';
import { ActivityIndicator, StyleSheet,View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

export default class BrowserScreen extends Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
           connectionStatus: false,
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      const {navigation} = this.props;
      this.focusListener = navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => {
      this.checkConnected();

      })
    }

   async checkConnected() {
      const networkState = await NetInfo.fetch();
      if (networkState.isConnected) {
        this.setState({ connectionStatus: true });
      }
  }

    LoadingIndicatorView() {
        return <ActivityIndicator 
                  color='#009b88' 
                  size='large' 
                  style={styles.ActivityIndicatorStyle} 
            />
    }

    render() {
    
        let url = this.props.navigation.getParam('webUrl');
        console.log(url) ;

        return (      
            /**
             * use the webview here to display the webpage
             */ 

            connectionStatus ? (
                  <WebView 
                     source={{ uri: url }}  
                     renderLoading={this.LoadingIndicatorView}
                     startInLoadingState={true}
                   /> 
                ) :
                (
                <View>
                  <Text> No Connection !!!!</Text>
                </View>)
                
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    ActivityIndicatorStyle: {
      flex: 1,
      justifyContent: 'center'
    }
  })
```

Comment: You need to refer to the variable correctly... `connectionStatus ?` -> `this.state.connectionStatus ?`

Comment: I have modified the 'connectionStatus` to  `this.state.connectionStatus'  but now the the `NO Connection ` is shown first before while the link is being loaded..  Can anyone help ?

Comment: Please create a new post for new issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`connectionStatus` is stored in state, refer to it as `this.state.connectionStatus`